# Django tuple/choices field is not translating

Tags: python, django, django-models, translation, lazy-evaluation

I have an Integer ModelField with a set of choices.

`field = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES_CONSTANT)`

This `CHOICES_CONSTANT` is defined in another file and imported

```
CHOICES_CONSTANT = (
    (0, _('One')),
    (1, _('Two')),
    ...
)
```

The `_` is from `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _` as the model field requires you to use lazy translations.

I also import the `CHOICES_CONSTANT` into other files (such as reports) where in a report I might say `str(dict(CHOICE_CONSTANT)[object.field]) if object.field else ''`.

**This** `str(dict(CHOICES_CONSTANT)[object.field]) if object.field else ''` does not get translated. In fact, if I just `print(CHOICES_CONSTANT)` it immediately evaluates to the default language (English).

In other places I would do `object.get_field_display()` and that also does not translate.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I spent too long on this looking in the wrong direction...

The lazy loaded translations were working correctly. The issue was that `LOCALE_PATHS` in `settings.py` did not include the root directory `locale/` folder. The constants `CHOICES_CONSTANT` and others were store in the project directory, rather than an app so the app was not getting the translations from the root directory.